# Is Google making a stackoverflow rip-off?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Baraza: impact on SO franchise?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70284/google-baraza-impact-on-so-franchise)

Google seems to be sneaking in their own answers software, in a different language.

It does seem to be very similar in features and functionality.

And it's not stackexchange :D

[**otvety.google.ru**](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/label?lid=2c13b5b22e90563e&clk=cts_ls)

Comment: This really belongs on the meta-wiki.
Please see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks, I've found this  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70284/google-baraza-impact-on-so-franchise

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not new. Google used to have "Google answers" long time ago, probably before stackoverflow was even popular. For some reason, Google has cancelled this project:
http://answers.google.com/answers/

The "otvety" just means "answers" in Russion, so it's just a localized version of Google answers. So it looks like it was not cancelled in some local markets like Russia.

Comment: Google answers pre-dated this and was rather different.

Comment: google answers, was very far from what you see on russian version. it looks like one of the first versions of bbforums, "otvety" has a very similar funtionality to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

They've also created [one for Africa](http://www.google.com/baraza/en/).